# DateTime error while insert to MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I come up with an error while inserting the following data into MySQL. How can I fix it?

ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 18:33:55' for column 'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('1', '17/07/2013 18:33:55', 'WNGSite1', '13.1', '81', '45')
```

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 18:18:53' for column
>   'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('2', '17/07/2013 18:18:53', 'WNGSite1', '13', '80', '45')
```

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 18:03:54' for column
>   'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('3', '17/07/2013 18:03:54', 'WNGSite1', '12.7', '80', '45')
```

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 17:48:54' for column
>   'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('4', '17/07/2013 17:48:54', 'WNGSite1', '12.7', '80', '45')
```

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 17:33:55' for column
>   'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('5', '17/07/2013 17:33:55', 'WNGSite1', '12.8', '80', '45')
```

> ERROR 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '17/07/2013 17:18:55' for column
>   'TimeStamp' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `wngtest`.`sitereading` (`idSiteReading`, `TimeStamp`, `SiteLocation`, `Flow`, `Temperature1`, `Temperature2`) VALUES ('6', '17/07/2013 17:18:55', 'WNGSite1', '12.9', '80', '45')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively, you can automatically re-format your date string to SQL-99 format using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE( '17/07/2013 18:33:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

So the INSERT statement would be:

```
INSERT INTO wngtest.sitereading 
(idSiteReading, TimeStamp, SiteLocation, Flow, Temperature1, Temperature2) 
VALUES ('1', 
STR_TO_DATE( '17/07/2013 18:33:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
'WNGSite1', '13.1', '81', '45');
```

Answer (score 12):

In MySql dates should be inserted in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Try using the format:

`2013-07-17 17:18:55`

Full Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO wngtest.sitereading 
(idSiteReading, TimeStamp, SiteLocation, Flow, Temperature1, Temperature2) 
VALUES ('1', '2013-07-17 18:33:55', 'WNGSite1', '13.1', '81', '45');
```

Comment: but I type '2100-06-04 00:00:00' into a query mysql also errs