# Incorrect datetime value for future date in mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL statement:

```
insert into `banners` 
    (`path`, `app_id`, `enabled`, `from_date`, `to_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values 
    ('banners/example.png', 'com.example.ccp_attacker', 1, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-12-31 00:00:00', '2100-06-04 00:00:00', '2100-06-04 00:00:00')
```

generates error `#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2100-06-04 00:00:00' for column 'updated_at' at row 1`

Why 2100-06-04 00:00:00 is not a valid time?

Comment: Take a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870222/datetime-error-while-insert-to-mysql) might be related.

Comment: Is `updated_at` a `TIMESTAMP` column?

Comment: It is on a DATE column.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL date does not exceed 2038. This is a very old problem and for some reason, they are not solving it. The max value for an acceptable date in MySQL is `2038`. When I faced this issue I saved the date in MySQL as `varchar` and later converted it to date in the business logic.

Comment: More information about [the Year 2038 Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it).

Comment: Convert from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720700/how-convert-field-from-timestamp-to-datetime